Nothing inside /usr/bin is recognised - bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
I was trying to install cups into the system, using these suggestions:

sudo apt install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall --install=no   sudo dpkg -i *.debwell

It was this point that my system was messed up. I have one terminal currently open, and as bash is not available, I am unable to open new ones.
hutber@hutber:~/Drivers/LW5xx_Linux$ sudo checkinstall --install=no

checkinstall 1.6.3, Copyright 2010 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.

Making install in ppd/Linux
/bin/bash: line 21: cd: ppd/Linux: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:364: install-recursive] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup.../usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory


/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 102: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 319: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 320: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory


/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory

Version 22.04
So it is indeed the checkinstall bug. Now I have a problem with trying to create the correct symlink whilst mounted...
base) hutber@hutber:/mnt/root$ ll
total 116
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4096 Nov 28 09:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Nov 28 09:10 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Aug 12 13:14 1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Feb  2  2024 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 21 11:44 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 cdrom/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 12 13:15 .config/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 164 root root 12288 Nov 27 22:56 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Jan  9  2024 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb  2  2024 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 media/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb 14  2024 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  4096 Sep 19 13:30 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 proc/
drwx------  13 root root  4096 Oct  8 13:00 root/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Feb  2  2024 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 srv/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 18  2022 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  49 root root 20480 Nov 27 23:01 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Apr 11  2024 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Feb 14  2024 var/

Could I please get some information if possible on why the vote for close so I might correct the issue?

Please confirm your Ubuntu version with cat /etc/os-release. You stated that you use 21.04 which is End of Life and therefore not supported anymore, neither by Canonical nor by Ask Ubuntu..

Thanks mook765! So its: 22.04

That's fine. A point I don't understand is how the question title and the question body go together. And that cat seemed to work contraindicates the statement in the title, obviously usr/bin/cat is recognized.

Your symptoms sound somewhat similar to PSA: Checkinstall can "brick" your Ubuntu 22.04 system - please [edit] your question to include the output of /bin/busybox ls -ld /lib

Do join the launchpad bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/1847582 and the 10 yr old  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/165074

Thanks guys I'll get the output up in a few mins. @mook765 actually cat wasn't working but Tab was showing the resulting finders available

Thanks guys, once I worked out how to create the link, it fixed the system!!! Life savers!
